# React Native error missing semicolon convert const App

Tags: react-native

> I want to convert the below code block to const App = () => format. How can I do it ?
> I'm getting 'error missing semicolon' error in the constructor when I try to do it.
> I don't want to use the render structure but I couldn't find the solution either.

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      categes: [
        { cat_id: '1', cat_name: 'abc', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '2', cat_name: 'xyz', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '3', cat_name: 'pqr', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '4', cat_name: 'uvw', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
        { cat_id: '5', cat_name: 'hij', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
      ],
      change: false,
    };
  }

  changeBackground = item => {
    let categes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.categes));

    for (let x = 0; x < this.state.categes.length; x++) {
      if (this.state.categes[x].cat_id == item.cat_id) {
        categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#0000FF';

        this.setState({
          categes: categes,
        });
      } else {
        categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#ED2525';

        this.setState({
          categes: categes,
        });
      }
    }
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.categes.map((item, key) => (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={{
              width: 200,
              height: 60,
              alignItems: 'center',
              justifyContent: 'center',
              margin: 10,
              backgroundColor: item.backgroundcolor,
            }}
            onPress={() => this.changeBackground(item)}>
            <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
              {' '}
              {item.cat_name.toUpperCase()}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Functional components do not and can not have constructors as opposed to class components, so you can't use the constructor to set initial state. What you should instead do is convert your `this.state = { ... }` to `useState` hooks, which *do* works in functional components. You could even decide to have a separate `useState` for the `categas` and one for the `change` state variables. You can check out the docs here: https://react.dev/reference/react/Component#alternatives for more information on how to migrate to functional components.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by the @nbokmans your code will look like this

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { View, TouchableOpacity, Text } from 'react-native'
const App = (props) => {

const [categes, setCateges] = useState([
    { cat_id: '1', cat_name: 'abc', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
    { cat_id: '2', cat_name: 'xyz', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
    { cat_id: '3', cat_name: 'pqr', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
    { cat_id: '4', cat_name: 'uvw', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
    { cat_id: '5', cat_name: 'hij', backgroundcolor: '#ED2525' },
]);
const [change, setChange] = useState(false);

const changeBackground = item => {
    let __categes = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(categes));

    for (let x = 0; x < categes.length; x++) {
        if (categes[x].cat_id == item.cat_id) {
            __categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#0000FF';
            setCateges(__categes);
        } else {
            __categes[x].backgroundcolor = '#ED2525';
            setCateges(__categes);
        }
    }
}

return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        {categes.map((item, key) => (
            <TouchableOpacity
                style={{
                    width: 200,
                    height: 60,
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    margin: 10,
                    backgroundColor: item.backgroundcolor,
                }}
                onPress={() => changeBackground(item)}>
                <Text style={{ color: '#FFFFFF' }}>
                    {' '}
                    {item.cat_name.toUpperCase()}
                </Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        ))}
    </View>
  );
}
export default App;
```